# <opencv2/opencv.hpp>, <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>, <opencv2/highgui.hpp> no such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, header

First I installed Cmake and opencv. Then installed OpenCV on QT using mingw32-make etc by adding environmental. I included the libs in .pro file. I have no idea why those includes are not found.

imagetest1.pro file include library parts

```
INCLUDEPATH += D:\opencv\build\include

LIBS += C:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_core410.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_highgui410.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_imgcodecs410.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_imgproc410.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_features2d410.dll
LIBS += C:\opencv-build\bin\libopencv_calib3d410.dll
```

main.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace  cv;
int main()
{
//Some code
}
```

changing to opencv4/opencv.hpp etc and the others gave the same error.

Comment: Does your directory `D:\opencv\build\include` contain the correct folder and hpp files? (e.g. the folder "opencv2" and in that folder the files "opencv.hpp"...)?

Comment: INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\build\include the problem was in include part! It was recognised as a command instead of a regular folder name

Answer (score 0):

I m also using Qt and OpenCV together and I added OpenCV libraries on .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv // for path

LIBS += `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` // for libraries
```

But before doing that be sure about that you installed opencv correctly. If you are using Ubuntu, run the command on terminal:

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
```

This should give an output opencv version(something like 3.4.3, 4.0).

Comment: INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\build\include the problem was in include part! It was recognised as a command instead of a regular folder name